# Bind actions to some html then append

Tags: jquery

Let's imagine that we have some piece of html with appended actions.

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');
html.find('a').bind('click', function(e) {
   alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

Now we want append this piece of html (with binded actions) to some `<div id="destination"></div>`.

```
$('#destination').append(html);
```

Is it possible?  (see [jsfidder](http://jsfiddle.net/6v5NJ/11/))

I need this functionality to bind some actions for modal window's content and then append this content to modal window's html wrapper and then invoke `Modal.show()`. So

Is it good practice or it is not recommended to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept should work fine. The problem with your fiddle is the use of `find`, which looks at descendant elements, but your `a` element isn't a descendant. Use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');
html.filter('a').bind('click', function(e) {
    alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/6v5NJ/12/).

Alternatively, you could use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (if you're using jQuery 1.7+) or `delegate` to attach the event handler to `#destination`:

```
$("#destination").on("click", "a", function() {
    alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

If you do that, you may want to give the `a` element some identifier, otherwise the event handler will execute for any `a` descendant of `#destination`.

**Edit** (based on comments)

As noted by @RoryMcCrossan in the comments, in this case you can actually remove `filter` completely. This is because there is just the one element in the jQuery object. However, if you've shortened the code for the purposes of the question, be careful, as removing `filter` in that case would bind the event handler to all of the elements:

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');
html.bind('click', function(e) {
    alert('You clicked me!'); //Bound to all elements in `html`
});
```

Comment: +1 you can also remove the `.filter('a')` for better performance as there is only 1 element in the `html` variable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - True, but it's quite likely the OP has reduced the actual code for brevity in the question. Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `$('<a href="#">click me</a>');` is supposed to return the created element.

You should probably remove the `find('a')` call, like in the following sample:

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');
html.bind('click', function(e) {
   alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documentation of [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

there are no descendants for your html elements array. you can use filter() to find in DOM but here you can use `each()` directly as:

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');
html.each(function(index){

    $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
   alert('You clicked me!');
});
});
$('#destination').append(html); //click not works :(
```

Check updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjankala/6v5NJ/15/).

Answer (score 0):

Just bind events after appending (html becomes actual DOM object).

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');

$('#destination').append(html).find('a').click(function(e) {
   alert('You clicked me!');
});
```

or bind for html

```
var html = $('<a href="#">click me</a>');
html.click(function(e) {
   alert('You clicked me!');
});
$('#destination').append(html);
```